# Stochastic Volatility CIR estimation

Tags: r, stochastic-volatility, estimation, matlab

Would anyone have a code (pref. Matlab or R) for any type of estimation (QML, GMM) not using option prices of a stochastic volatility model driven by a CIR process described below?

\begin{equation}
dS_t = \mu dt + \sqrt{v_t} dW_t^1
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
dv_t = \kappa (\theta - v_t) dt + \sigma \sqrt{v_t} dW^2_t
\end{equation}
such that $dW_{t}^{1}\,dW_{t}^{2}=\rho dt$

I just need to cross-check my results.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the Heston model. You will find plenty of information on this site and also implementations on Google. Plus, in R it's already implemented (packages fOptions and NMOF). Remember that the Heston model models also the correlation between the two Wiener processes.

Comment: @Arrigo: Thanks, there's been a typo in the price process specification. Unlike for Heston, I need to estimate without using the option prices.

Comment: Here it is! [Heston calibration in Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29446-heston-model-calibration-and-simulation)

Comment: Answers should contain enough information to actually answer the question. A simple link to another site should just be a comment.

Comment: @GabrielePompa I agree with Joshua Ulrich and converted your answer to a comment. Your link looks interesting so please feel free to elaborate on the link you've provided in a new answer.

Comment: @SchnitzelRaver it would help if you give some input and output of your code so that, for example, users can show you how to run the code they provide with your set of parameters. Using different dimensions for parameters always gives strange results.

Comment: @GabrielePompa thanks. but this is not a heston model (doesn't assume dependency between the wieners) + for calibration of the heston option prices are needed, which i do not have.

Answer (score 1):

1. Purpose:

   - CIR process maximum likelihood estimation.
2. Input

   - Model.Data       = Time series of interest rates observations.
   - Model.TimeStep  = Delta t; recommended: 1/250 for daily data and 1/12 for monthly data.
   - Model.Disp       = 'y'  |  'n',  (default: 'n').
   - Model.Method     =  'ncx2pdf'   |   'besseli'  (default: 'besseli').
   - Model.MatlabDisp = 'off' | 'iter' | 'notify' |' final' (default: 'off').
3. Output:

   - Results.Params   = Estimated parameters (kappa, theta, sigma).
   - Results.Fval     = Objective function value.

---

```
function Results = CIRestimation(Model)
Nobs = length(Model.Data);
r = Model.Data(1:end-1);
dr = diff(Model.Data);           
dr = dr./r.^0.5;
regressors = [Model.TimeStep./r.^0.5, Model.TimeStep*r.^0.5];
drift = regressors\dr;
res = regressors*drift - dr;
alpha = -drift(2);
theta = -drift(1)/drift(2);
sigma = sqrt(var(res, 1)/Model.TimeStep);
InitialParams = [kappa theta sigma];
if ~isfield(Model, 'Disp'), Model.Disp = 'y'; 
end;
if strcmp(Model.Disp, 'y')
    fprintf('\n initial kappa=...%+3.6f\n initial theta=...%+3.6f\n initial sigma = %+3.6f\n',kappa, theta, sigma);
end
if ~isfield(Model, 'MatlabDisp'), Model.MatlabDisp = 'off';
end;
options = optimset('LargeScale', 'off', 'MaxIter', 300, 'MaxFunEvals',300, 'Display', Model.MatlabDisp, 'TolFun', 1e-4, 'TolX', 1e-4, 'TolCon', 1e-4); 
if ~isfield(Model, 'Method'), Model.Method = 'besseli'; 
end;
if strcmp(Model.Method, 'ncx2pdf')
    [Params, Fval, Exitflag] =  fminsearch(@(Params) CIRobjective2(Params, Model),InitialParams, options);   
else
    [Params, Fval, Exitflag] =  fminsearch(@(Params) CIRobjective1(Params, Model),InitialParams, options);   
end   
Results.Params = Params;
Results.Fval = -Fval/Nobs;
Results.Exitflag = Exitflag;

if strcmp(Model.Disp, 'y')
    fprintf('\n kappa = %+3.6f\n theta    = %+3.6f\n sigma = %+3.6f\n',...
        Params(1), Params(2), Params(3));
    fprintf(' log-likelihood = %+3.6f\n', -Fval/Nobs);
end
```

end